# Copy just the values of date to another cell

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, excel-formula

I am trying to copy the current date and time based on below

`if a cell in column E changes to Contacted, then need add the timestamp but it should not change when the next time i open the excel`

I am editing the column E by manually, see below picture

[image]

I know that to catch the date I use NOW() but my issue is the next day when I open the excel sheet it's changing the date to that date. I don't need that.

I want the date to occur only one time and don't change it. How can I do this? Any answers are highly appreciated

I am trying the below code but it does not work

`=IF((E2)="Contacted",NOW(),"")`

Comment: I'd suggest approaching with via vba and using the appropriate Worksheet event handler (with `Worksheet_Change`, seeming the best fit for you're trying to do). Therein, you could simply test for (per your e.g.) E2 changing and test for the target cell being empty. If so, write the date. If not leave it be.

Comment: Could you elaborate on *based on an event in excel*? You concluded that `NOW()` is useless. `=IF((E2)="Contacted",NOW(),"")` is a formula, not a code. You used the words *event* and *code* which are, probably unintentionally, saying that it can only be done by using `VBA`, not by using a formula. More details are necessary. Edit your question by adding them. Or is the last formula saying: if a cell in column `E` changes to `Contacted`, add the timestamp? But it's not clear in which column to add it. Please do clarify.

Comment: ok updated. ` if a cell in column E changes to Contacted, then need add the timestamp but it should not change when the next time i open the excel`

Comment: @Spinner do you know if there is a way not to change the change the date in a cell, every day when i open the excel sheet.

Comment: You haven't shared the column to put in the timestamp. Important is also, how the value will change to `Contacted`: manually, by writing into the cell, or by formula. Also, you could add the `vba` tag to your question to attract more attention.

Comment: @VBasic2008ok added vba tag, I change the column E to "Contacted" by manual

Comment: Just need the column and if manually or by formula (read my previous comment).

Comment: @HumMing birD: Erm... yes: As I said "test for the **target** cell being empty". Premise being the target cell (i.e. where you want to write the date) has nothing until your code adds it.

Comment: @VBasic2008 added the column picture

Comment: Good oh. But you also need to understand that SO isn't a free coding service. You have been given pointers. So now you need to make an effort to solve the problem yourself (i.e. write the code). If having issues with that, show the parts of your code you're having problems with, and explain why that isn't doing what you want. See [help] for details on asking a valid question.

Comment: @Spinner bro i just need to to know how to copy the date one time to another cell. I know to copy any value from one cell to another but my issue is i dont want to change the date becasue my formuala in cell F is refering to `=NOW()` but how can i just copy this date as of one time and not change it when i open the excel file in future

Comment: Getting beyond comments here, See below for fully exploitation.

Comment: @Spinner Mate this is what i have done now. but Target cell will change date for every other day when i open the excel sheet due to formula = NOW().. I dont need like that. The date where the cell being of interesst (i.e. in Columns("E") when changed to "Contacted" then i want the date to stay there forever. I dont want to change this

Comment: At a loss here. What I've suggested below is a way to do just that. However, it also assumes some understanding of programming (in which case it should be clear enough). If that's the case, read it again and attempt to implement. If not, suggest working with someone in your company that does or hiring a contractor.

Comment: Do not use `Now` as part of a formula. Use the VBA `Now` to create a new timestamp, and put that value directly into the cell.

Answer (score 2):

Further to my comments above: What I'm suggesting is to drop the formula entirely.

Instead, write a vba `Worksheet_Change` event handler.
o Example given in vba help shows you how do that.
o This sub goes into the worksheet's code module.

In the event handler test for:

1. Changed cell being of interest (i.e. in `Columns("E")` )
2. Changed cell value is of interest (i.e. `= "Contacted"`)
3. Target cell (i.e. where the timestamp goes) being empty (i.e. `= ""`)

If conditions met: **Write** timestamp **value** to the Target cell (i.e. `= Now()`)

Note: You'll likely want to also handle operator errors (e.g. change to Contacted, and then changed to something else).
In which case, you'll want to clear the relevant timestamp cell.

Answer (score 1):

### Add Timestamp on Drop-Down Value

- Copy the following into the sheet module e.g. `Sheet1` (not `ThisWorkbook` and not `Module1`) of the mentioned worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Const sCriteria As String = "Contacted" ' Source Criteria
    Const sFirst As String = "E2" ' where the criteria will be searched for
    Const dCol As String = "F" ' where the time stamp will be added
    
    Dim scrg As Range ' Source Column Range
    With Me.Range(sFirst)
        Set scrg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(scrg, Target)

    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no change in the source column range
        
    Dim sCell As Range ' Source Cell
    Dim dwrg As Range ' Destination Write Range
    Dim dCell As Range ' Destination Cell
    
    ' Combine the cells to be written to into a range ('dwrg').
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        Set dCell = sCell.EntireRow.Columns(dCol)
        If IsEmpty(dCell) Then ' destination cell is empty
            If CStr(sCell.Value) = sCriteria Then ' is 'sCriteria'
                If dwrg Is Nothing Then ' combine first cell
                    Set dwrg = dCell
                Else ' combine any but the first cell
                    Set dwrg = Union(dwrg, dCell)
                End If
            'Else ' is not 'sCriteria'
            End If
        'Else ' destination cell is not empty
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    ' Disable events to not retrigger this or any other while writing
    ' the timestamp(s).
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' Write the timestamp in one go.
    If Not dwrg Is Nothing Then ' at least one cell combined
        dwrg.Value = Now
    'Else ' no cells combined
    End If

SafeExit:
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then ' events disabled
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    'Else ' events enabled
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```